# Threading with Pyside6 and qml

Tags: qml, pyside6

With PyQT5 and QtDesigner I used to make window app with threading like that:

```
class MainUIClass(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):

  def __init__(self,parent=None):
    super().__init__()
    self.setupUi(self)

    #Create threads    
    self.thread_1 = QThread()
 
    # Create worker object
    self.worker_1 = Worker_1(self)

    # Move workers to thread
    self.worker_1.moveToThread(self.thread_1)

    # Connect signals and slots
    self.thread_1.started.connect(self.worker_1.run)

    self.thread_1.start(QThread.Priority.NormalPriority)
```

where Worker_1 is like:

```
class Worker_1(QObject):   
   def __init__(self,mainWin,parent = None  ):
       super(CoreWorker, self).__init__(parent)
       #super().__init__()
       self.mainWin = mainWin
  
   def run(self):
    
     while True:
       pass
       # do something
```

**and main**

```
if __name__ == '__main__':

 app = QApplication(sys.argv)
 win = MainUIClass()
 win.show()

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Similarly for thread 2,3,...

Now I want try to make something similar with PySide but for design I want to use qml (in QtCreator) instead of using Ui_MainWindow from QT designer. Maybe the main difference (problem) is not in converting from PyQT to Pyside but from converting from qt designer to to qml.

Is there any help please?

Comment: How is your question relates to threading exactly?

Comment: Yes.. I don't know how to grasp the question. I just want to create (python) app with threads by using qml language for front-end. But I could not find any real example, or tutorial about this..

Comment: It is not different than Qt-widgets.

Comment: Here is an example https://github.com/nrbnlulu/Qt-answers/tree/master/QtQuick/qml-python-interaction-via-thread

Comment: @WITC 1. QML is only related to the UI, while threading is clearly *not* for that (since all UI management always has to happen in the main thread); 2. due to the above, creating QThread subclasses or worker QObjects moved to a QThread makes no difference whether you're using QWidgets, QML (or no UI at all); 3. Using PySide or PyQt changes almost nothing, and certainly not in the implementation of threading;

Comment: Thank you! It really helped me to clarify a few things.